# Finding a button on page using Playwright

Tags: c#, .net, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I am trying to find a button on page following the documentation here
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/locators#locating-elements

The issue is the button will show the size of the file "Download (300KB)" and under testing it cannot find the button to click it and produce an action
This is my current code which is just timing out

```
var download1 = await Page.RunAndWaitForDownloadAsync(async () =>
        {
            await Page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new()
                {
                    NameRegex = new Regex("\\W*((?i)Download(?-i))\\W*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                }).ClickAsync();
        });
```

Comment: Please share the actual webpage

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue could be it **appears like a button but there might not be a button tag** in it

if you go to [this site](https://www.duplichecker.com/compress-pdf-to-300kb.php) , you will notice there is an upload button, but in DOM it says its a label though externally it appears like a button

I tried the same code you have given on another site and it worked as the button is actually under a button tag.

```
    await Page.GotoAsync("https://bigpdf.11zon.com/en/compress-pdf/compress-pdf-to-300kb.php");
    var download1 = await Page.RunAndWaitForDownloadAsync(async () =>
    {
        await Page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new()
        {
            NameRegex = new Regex("Select PDF", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        }).ClickAsync();
    });
```